# Best way to wait for flag in thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a C++ program with multiple threads running. I am using global flags to tell me when I can continue my program. This requires the use of while loops that wait for a flag to be set. I know this method is not the best because the program is taking much longer to run than expected.

I have seen the use of mutex and conditional variables but I am not sure if it is applicable to my needs or how to implement.

```cpp
volatile bool flag;

int threadFunction(){
    //Do some initialization work
    //
    //Then look for flag to be set
    while (1){
        if (flag){
            //do stuff
            flag = false;
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
}

int setFlag(){
    flag = true;
}

int main(){
    std::thread thread1(threadFunction);
    while (1){
        setFlag();
        Sleep(5);
    }
    thread1.join()
}
```

The while loop in threadFunction seems to be causing the speed issues. Is there a better way to do this?

There are no errors but the code seems very inefficient.

Comment: Not really anything to do with your question, but almost always `if (flag) { do_stuff(); flag = false; }` is wrong. Better is   `if (flag) {  flag = false; do_stuff(); }`

Answer (score 2):

What you currently have is a busy wait, also sometimes called a spinlock.  These can provide good performance in some circumstances (mainly when waits are short and infrequent), but can also cause undue CPU load tying up CPU cores that could be doing productive work.

The other option is a blocking flag.  This will use OS-provided tools to block your thread while it waits for some condition.  This will prevent it from tying up CPU resources doing nothing, since the OS knows it can schedule another thread for as long as your thread is waiting.  It can also increase latency, since, once the condition your thread is waiting for happens, the OS has to get around to scheduling your thread again.  With a spinlock your thread is already executing and can use the remainder of its time slice doing productive work immediately.

You can build a simple blocking flag from a condition variable and a mutex:

```
class Flag
{
public:
    Flag() : flag_{false} {}

    void set()
    {
        std::lock_guard g(mutex_);
        flag_ = true;
        cond_var_.notify_all();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        std::lock_guard g(mutex_);
        flag_ = false;
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex_);
        cond_var_.wait(lock, [this]() { return flag_; });
    }
private:
    bool flag_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_var_;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6ba205e7ad154fc)

---

Which type of locking mechanism you need will depend heavily on your particular workload.  As with all performance questions, the only way to know which will be best for you is to benchmark.

Comment: `flag` should be `std::atomic`, I think.

Comment: @PaulSanders it doesn't need to be atomic. It's the predicate data, and as such *all* access should already be mutually exclusive thanks to that mutex.

Comment: @PaulSanders `flag_` doesn't need to be atomic here since the mutex provides a memory barrier.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Not that it's a big deal, but moving the `notify_all` call to inside the block that holds the mutex improves performance. A good implementation then knows that the `notify_all` call can't possibly make a thread ready-to-run and can't contend with anything, allowing it to execute on the fast path. Since the OP was concerned about performance, it seems like a good idea to do it the best way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Interesting.  I've always heard the opposite advice: that you should avoid notifying the threads waiting on a condition variable while you hold the relevant mutex, since the threads would just wake up and immediately block again.  I'll have to do some further reading.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That would be a poor implementation that senselessly made a thread ready-to-run just to immediately block it on a mutex. I wouldn't optimize my code to work well on a poor implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have a "busy wait" and/or latency issues in the code.

Use `std::condition_variable` along with an `std::mutex`.
See the C++ reference for details. It has all the examples and explanations you would need.

Comment: Also `volatile bool flag;` should be `std::atomic <bool> flag;`